# Cancel NSData initWithContentsOfURL in NSOperation

Tags: ios, nsdata, nsoperation

I currently have the following code in an NSOperation that has an observer for keyPath "isCancelled":

```
    downloaded = FALSE;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
    dataXML = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    downloaded = TRUE;
```

I want to make it so that the observeValueForKeyPath function is able to cancel the dataXML continuing or just completely stop the NSOperation once the NSOperation is sent a cancel message. The NSOperation's cancelling operation cancel only notifies the operation that it should stop, but will not force my operation's code to stop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't cancel it.

If you want to be able to cancel the load mid-way through, use `NSURLConnection` operating in asynchronous mode. It's a bit more work to set up but you can cancel at any point in the download process.

Alternatively, you could use [this handy class](https://github.com/nicklockwood/RequestQueue) I wrote that wraps an async `NSURLConnection` and its delegate in a single method call ;-)

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[RequestQueue mainQueue] addRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    if (data && error == nil)
    {
        //do something with your downloaded data
    }
}];

//to cancel the download at any time, just say
[[RequestQueue mainQueue] cancelRequest:request];
```

Easy!

`</shamelessSelfPromotion>`

Note that the request above is already asynchronous, and the class already manages queuing of multiple requests, so you don't need to (and shouldn't) wrap it in an `NSOperationQueue`.

Comment: That makes sense, but there's nothing stopping you from kicking off a separate XML operation from inside the success block once the download is complete. I just meant you shouldn't do the request itself inside your NSOperatiom because spawning a thread from within another thread is just a waste of resources. Although if you want to you can, as log as you create a new RequestQueue instance for each NSOperation, as the mainQueue shared instance isn't thread safe.

Comment: Thank you!!!! Your code's really helped me: I have TIFF's that are nearly 500mb (honestly) in size and now I can cancel loads that were mistakenly started! Brilliant.