# Displaying full-sized camera raw files in OSX

Tags: macos, nsdata, nsimage, cgimage

This has been driving me mad for months: I have a little app to preview camera raw images. As the files in question can be quite big and stored on a slow network drive I wanted to offer the user a chance to stop the loading of the image.

Handily I found this thread:

[Cancel NSData initWithContentsOfURL in NSOperation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117332/cancel-nsdata-initwithcontentsofurl-in-nsoperation/9117373#comment18601134_9117373)

and am using Nick's great convenience method to cache the data and be able to issue a cancel request halfway through.

Anyway, once I have the data I use:

```
NSImage *sourceImage = [[NSImage alloc]initWithData:data];
```

The problem comes when looking at Nikon .NEF files; `sourceImage` returns only a thumbnail and not the full size. Displaying Canon .CR2 files and in fact, any other .TIFF's and .JPEG's seems fine and `sourceImage` is the expected size. I've checked the amount of data that is being loaded (with `NSLog` and `[data length]`) and it does seem that all of the Nikon files' 12mb is there for the `-initWithData:`

If I use

```
NSImage *sourceImage = [[NSImage alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myNEFURL];
```

then I get the full sized image of the Nikon files but of course the app blocks.

So after poking around for what is beginning to feel like my entire life I think I know that the problem is related to the Nikon's metadata stating that the file's DPI is 300 whereas Canon et al is 72.

I hoped a solution would be to lazily access the file with:

```
NSImage*tempImg = [[NSImage alloc] initByReferencingURL:myNEFURL];
```

and having seen similar postings here and elsewhere I found a common possible answer of simply

```
[sourceImage setSize:tempImg.size];
```

but of course this just resizes the tiny thumbnail up to 3000x2000 or thereabouts.

I've been messing with the following hoping that they would provide a way to get the big picture from the .NEF:

```
CGImageSourceRef isr = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)data, NULL);
CGImageRef isrRef = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(isr, 0, NULL);
```

and

```
NSBitmapImageRep *bitMapIR = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:data];
```

But checking the sizes on these show similar thumbnail widths and heights. In fact, `isrRef` returns an even smaller thumbnail, one that is 4.2 times smaller. Perhaps worth noting that 300 / 72 == 4.2, so `isrRef` is taking account of the DPI on an image where the DPI (possibly) has already been observed.

Please! Can someone [nicely] put me out of my misery and help me get the full-sized image from the loaded data?!?! Currently, I'm special-case'ing the NEF files with a case insensitive search on the file extension and then loading the URL with the blocking methods. I have to take a hit on the app blocking and the search can't be fool-proof in the long run.

As an aside: is this actually a bug in the OS? It does seem like `NSImage's -initWithData:` and `-initWithContentsOfURL:` methods use different engines to actually render the image. Would it not be reasonable to have assumed that `-initWithURL:` simply loads the data which then gets rendered just as though it had been presented to the class with `-initWithData:` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug - confirmed when I did a DTS. Apparently I need to file a bug report. Currently the only way is to use the NSURL methods. Instead of checking the file extension I should probably traverse the meta dictionaries and check the manufacturer's entry for "Nikon", though...